# Get an Error Message when sending Email to Sandbox

Tags: apex-email-service, decrypt

I want to send an Email to my salesforce `Account` and the update `Account` informations given in the Email.
My problem now: The Email is Encrypted. So i wrote an Apex class and now I'm trying to implement the decryption.
Before, it already worked sending an Email an creating an test-Task, but now, while trying to decode the Email, i get an Email back with the following

> Error: System.SecurityException: update() failed.

```
(System Code) Class.UpdateLeadsWithHomeReporting.Decrypt: line 27, column 1
             Class.UpdateLeadsWithHomeReporting.handleInboundEmail: line 13, column 1 
11:42:04.102 (102347358)|FATAL_ERROR|System.SecurityException: update() failed
```

My Code:

```
    String encodedAesKey = 'mySecretAESKey';
    Blob key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encodedAesKey);

    Blob input = Blob.valueof('MyEncryptedString');

    Blob ivBlob = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex('myIVInHex');
    Blob output = Crypto.decrypt('AES256', key, ivBlob , input);
```

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone know?

Comment: (System Code)
Class.UpdateLeadsWithHomeReporting.Decrypt: line 27, column 1
Class.UpdateLeadsWithHomeReporting.handleInboundEmail: line 13, column 1
11:42:04.102 (102347358)|FATAL_ERROR|System.SecurityException: update() failed.

Answer (score 0):

I now know what my problem was, so I guess that's why the error message was thrown. I forgot to encode my input String from base64, I do it now and everything works perfectly.